# POST doesn't send data

Tags: rest, post, spring-mvc, angularjs

I'm using Angularjs and spring mvc 3. I have in my controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/elprocesses")
public class ELProcessController {
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/elprocess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void save(@RequestBody final Entity01 entity01, 
    @RequestBody final Entity02 entity02
        ) {
    ...
}
```

ELProcessController.js :

```
$scope.saveForm = function(selectedname01) {
    $http.post('elprocesses/elprocess', {entity01:selectedname01, entity02:selectedname02});
...
}
```

it doesn't enter in my spring controller method, but when I send only one data with `$http.post('elprocesses/elprocess', selectedname01);`
and changing my controller class with:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/elprocess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void save(@RequestBody final Entity01 entity01)
```

this works fine,

What am I doing wrong to send entity01 and entity02?

Comment: I think on the Angular side you have it okay but on the Spring side I think it may just be one entity since you're just sending one object with two properties not really two objects on the javascript side.  I don't recall exactly how Spring determines which method to call (if it takes signature/parameter length as an indicator) but you can try by overloading the method.

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript, is selectedname02 defined anywhere?

If it is, then open up your network tab and you'll see whether or not it's sending data. The POST request has the header `Content-Type: application/json` by default though so make sure you're trying to get json data and not form encoded data or something. I'm not familiar with spring mvc at all so check their docs.

Comment: yes, selectedname02 is defined. In my network tab the data sent are: {"entity01":{"id":1,"name":"name1"},"entity02":"id":3,"name":"name3"}}, and Content-Type is application/json;charset=utf-8.

Comment: I think that is the way the'm posting, because when I send one parameter $http.post('elprocesses/elprocess',{entity01:selectedname01}); also does not work, which did not happen to me if I send in the form: $http.post('elprocesses/elprocess', selectedname01);.